# Default language for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, localization

When using Google Maps the web often displayed in Vietnamese. (I live in Vietnam.)

I want it default to be English. How can I do that?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Do webpages usually display in English, and using Google Maps causes them to change to Vietnamese?  Which language does Google Maps display in? Need some more info to provide an answer.

Comment: @nitrl Hi there, this may help us. When I add `hl=en`, I got what I want but that won't remain as default and I'm not very interested in adding that all the time. So my answer is Chorme browser, and yes using Google Maps causes the change. English is the language of my browser as all other software I use here.

Comment: Sounds like Google Maps is auto-detecting your location and then applying your current location to Chrome. Since there's no way to disable auto-detection of location, I can't think of any way to resolve the issue.

Comment: @nitrl Yeah. And this is so annoying

Comment: [Promoting my simple chrome extension (:] which will allow you to pick google maps language: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-language-pick/ppmggddpkpknmapgmoieokbfnpncmble

Comment: I am in Canada. I have English (US) as the primary language in my account. Google still switches maps' language to Russian. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 4):

I have had same problem. The solution is to add a language hint to the URL. Example:

```
https://maps.google.com/?hl=en
```

(The "en" is the two-letter code for English.)

Comment: This doesn’t change the **default** language.

Comment: indeed, default is at google account settings (not at search settings option that maps menu has btw on the web) and it seems to ignore browser preferences. So this is a nice trick for developers mostly who want to redirect to some map in a specific language

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can change the language of Google Maps is through your Google Account settings. Click on your email address on the top right hand corner and select Account. In the destination page, there is an option under Language and choose English (US) from the drop down.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I did this already and long ago. But the Google's sites are always automatically switch back to Vietnamese

Comment: That is weird, because I am also using a different language than the default and it works perfectly. Did you check your cookies settings?

Comment: How can I check the `cookies`?

Comment: Like for example, is your browser blocking cookies from google.com, or is cookies disabled? Afaik Google uses cookies to store your language preferences.

Comment: I had to change my language to Japanese and then change it back to English.